# Using out parameter in a function that has a return value

Tags: c#

I have a function such as this one:

```
public string MyFunction(int a, out int b)
{
   var test = ""
   b = 6;
   return test;
}
```

and then on the receiving end:

```
int b = 0;
var testOutcome = MyFunction(3, b);
```

I wonder how to get the value of: **b** in this scenario?

something like:

```
var bOutcome = ....;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) parameter from the method. Note that you also need to add the `out` keyword in the parameter signature of the method:

```
int b = 0;  // initialization is redundant
string  testOutcome = MyFunction(3, out b);
// b is initialized now
```

Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.

Comment: Small nitpick: The `b = 0` initialization in the calling method is extraneous.

Comment: @Douglas: i've added a comment.

Answer (score 2):

As written above your code will not compile because when using a method that receive an `out` parameter then you should add the keyword `out` also in the calling line.

You should change your calling line to

```
// No need to initialize b
// It is mandatory to initialize an out parameter for the called function
int b; 
var testOutcome = MyFunction(3, out b);
```

then your could simply check the value of b

```
if (b == 6)
```

A very common example scenario on how to use an out parameter is the [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method